# Fullcalendar eventDrop revertFunc error

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the eventDrop on fullcalendar in this way:

```
eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

            if (!confirm("are you sure?") {
                revertFunc();
            }
```

When revertFunc is launched I have this error in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: number is not a function
```

Could you help me?

Comment: can you show the script in revertFunc()

Comment: there is no script..maybe I lost to write some code?
I was inspired by this example http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

Comment: try replacing your `eventDrop` with `eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {`

Comment: You have an error in your code; you are missing another bracket in the if statement `if (!confirm("are you sure?") {`, should be `if (!confirm("are you sure?")) {`

Comment: @Joe What work worked?